# How to compile a directive which is loaded dynamically onclick event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

In my **app.js** I have

```
$scope.onclick = function(){
         // appending directve "exmDir" to body. 
           document.body.setAttribute('exm-dir', '');
}
```

The `exm-dir` is appending to body but it doesn't show its contents. How can I compile? Please help me.

Comment: Check out: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile. Prob in your case  $compile(document.body)($scope);

Comment: In which controller I should write? If I have `mainController` to the body and `dirCntrl` to the `exm-dir`.

Comment: inside `$scope.onclick` method after injecting `exm-dir` directive

Comment: but the directive content is replacing previous data & not showing even after I removed the directive from the element and recompiled again

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

`function compile(element){
    var el = angular.element(element);

    $scope = el.scope();
      $injector = el.injector();
      $injector.invoke(function($compile){
         $compile(el)($scope)
      })

  }`

`$scope.onclick = function(){
     // appending directve "exmDir" to body. 
     var el = document.body;
     el.setAttribute("exm-dir", "");
     compile(el);
 }`

Comment: showing injector() scope() are not functions of element